# VAR with exogenous variables

Tags: r, time-series

I am attempting a VAR model in R with an exogenous variable on:

```
VARM <- data.frame(y,x1,x2,x3)  #x3 is the exogenous variable
```

First, I want to choose the correct lag order by using VARselect

```
VARselect(VARM, lag.max = 6, type = "const" , exogen=x3)
```

I then get the following error : *"different row size of y and exogen"*

I can't figure out what's causing this.  When I view the data frame I have confirmed that the rows are the same and there is no missing observations.  I've tried various things to use the x3 variable, but the closest I could get is this error when the VARselect runs:

*"No column names supplied in exogen, using: exo1 , instead"*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems that you were almost there. In the details of `VARselect` it says: "providing a matrix object for exogen". If, in addition, you do not want to get a warning (not an error) such as "No column names supplied in exogen, using: exo1 , instead" you should provide named matrix. For example:

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(50), x2 = rnorm(50))
model <- VARselect(df, exogen = cbind(x3 = rnorm(50)))
```

Comment: AWESOME I guess I missed that in the PDF.  Once I stored the variable as a matrix it worked without a hitch, and also thanks for indicating the difference between 'warning' and 'model.'